# javascript dojo toolkit module definition

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is my first dojo application in javascript.
I have a problem about my module definiton. I am using CDN dojo file.

I have created a new folder named **dj** to create my custom modules. My first module is **first.js**

I am calling my module in my script as following but not working.

[image]

If I call the file like this

```
require(["dj/first.js"], function (first) {
        alert(first);
    });
```

I changed "dj/first" as "dj/frist.js" and worked.

But I wanna use "dj/first"

Comment: I think you are missing +"/dj" for your location, it should be location: ....+"/dj"

Comment: I tried this (location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, '')+"/dj") but didn't work.

Comment: You should look at your console (Network tab or something similar) and see what request you're actually executing. That will make it much easier to fix your regex.I used this regex: `location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '/assets/js/my'` for a **my** package in **assets/js**.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an interesting case, 
If I put the CDN dojo reference script under the dojoConfig script, it is working.

```
    <p id="hi">Hello</p>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script>

    require(["dj/first"], function (first) {
        alert(first);
    });
</script>
```

if I define CDN dojo script in head tag and under title tag, it is not working.
This is interesting.